# Windows Application installation on a 64 bit OS windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am running a setup of Windows application on a windows 10 64 bit OS.
Previously the win forms app had been running on 32bit windows 7 Os for last 14 years.

Every module works fine but not reports (crystal reports).

After installation the application is in Program files(x86).
I installed CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_19.
I installed CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_19.

Still the error shows

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Wasn't Windows 7 released in 2009...?

Comment: How is that relevant ? @JohnSaps

Comment: You wrote that the app has run for 14 years on Windows 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might mean that you need to have correct Crystal runtime. X64 for 64 bit machine and X86 for 32 bit machine.

Here is a list of all Crystal runtimes: [Crystal Reports Runtime Distribution & Supported Operating Systems](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?original_fqdn=wiki.sdn.sap.com&pageId=56787567)

Comment: Already tried intalling both separately and and at the same time also. No luck !!!

Comment: What is the crystal reports version in the application?

Comment: 12.0.2000.0 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

Comment: So you have earlier installed a runtime related to Crystal 13(13_0_19). So try installing a runtime from here and make sure it is RTM (12.0) 
https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-27917

Comment: shall I have to uninstall what is already intalled ? @samithagun

Comment: No need. You can keep it.

Comment: I tried installing 13_0_05 in Windows 8.1. And strangely it is working there !!!
Why not in Windows 10 !!! JFYI

Comment: Great! Please leave an up-vote if you are satisfied.